# OpenCart pass variable to twig from controller

Tags: php, controller, twig, opencart

Hy!

I need to use some data in twig files, how do I pass it from header.php to twig files? I created a new element in $data array, but It doesn't exist in the twig files.

```
$data['testvar'] = "test string";
```

And I try to access it in twig files like this:

```
{{ testvar }}
```

Comment: are you sure that you pass `$data` to a template, may be you need `$this->data['testvar'] = 'test string';`

Comment: I tried it but still the same :( Is it the right way Im trying to do? I mean passing var in the header.php? Some people mentioned the home.php.

Comment: Oh, I've understood, are you trying to pass a variable to another template, not to a template, which you call in you .php file

I mean, you are working with 'my-template.php', but want to pass a variable to 'header.php'?

Comment: Yes, im trying to pass a var from header.php to header.twig. Im confused, this method works at footer.php, and I can access my var in footer.twig, but It doesnt work in header.php. Im trying to call it in header.twig, but its not available there.

Comment: Try something like this in header.twig: `my text is {{ testvar }}`, then check your site, are you able to see plain text (`my text is`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you made some changes, you must  in admin dashboard refresh your modifications  and clear cache, blue gear icon in right upper corner.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `$data['testvar'] = "test string";` only in `catalog/controller/common/header.php`, than you can use `{{ testvar }}` only in `catalog/view/theme/Your theme (or default)/template/common/header.twig`.

---

To be sure what $data is communicate to view file, you can add `die(print_r($data));` before load view.