# opencart 3 how to Custom variable in twig page

Tags: php, twig, opencart-3

i want to show custom text come from a variable in language template.

so i declared a variable in:

```
admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/mytheme.php

$_['text_label_menu_count']  = 'Some count';
```

and then try to print that variable in

```
catalog/theme/mytheme/template/common/menu.twig

<h4 class="text-white"> {{ text_label_menu_count }} </h4>
```

but nothing happens.

Can you explain me how to achieve this? Thanks a lot

... I found a lot of twig similarities with angulajs.

Comment: Did you pass `$_` to the template?

Comment: can you be more axplanatory? i declared $_ in mytheme.php and try to echo that in menu.twig. You have a suggestion?

Comment: Possibly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52465396/opencart-pass-variable-to-twig-from-controller)

Comment: you cannot add the string to admin and then use it in the catalog ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to print some text from language file to TWIG

```
      catalog/view/theme/your_template/template/common/menu.twig

<h4 class="text-white"> {{ text_label_menu_count }} </h4>
```

Your language file should be placed to the corresponding folder... in this case to:

```
catalog/language/en-gb/common/menu.php

$_['text_label_menu_count']  = 'Some count';
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is wrong.
You cannot asign language variable in `admin` and used in `catalog`.

Now follow to below step:

**1. Language file**

asign value in language file

```
catalog\language\en-gb\common\your_language_file.php

$_['text_label_menu_count']  = 'Some count';
```

**2. Controller file**

call language file in controller where you would like to use language variable

```
catalog\controller\common\your_controller_file.php 

$this->load->language('common/your_language_file');
```

**3. Twig file**

Print variable in twig file

```
catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\your_view_file.twig

<h4 class="text-white"> {{ text_label_menu_count }} </h4>
```